# What package to install only the docker client (without engine) in Focal Fossa 20.04?

Tags: apt, software-installation, 20.04, docker, client

I've noticed that Ubuntu 20.04 (Focal Fossa) comes with the latest docker engine ready to be installed.

On may/2020 if you do:

```
# apt update
# apt install -y docker.io
```

you get docker version `19.03.8` which, in turn, is the latest published (to the date) by the docker friends.

This is amazing! This installs both the latest engine and client from the ubuntu's standard package repos. Great!

But now... I want to have a client machine **with only** the docker client. I don't want the engine itself downloaded in this machine. Only the client part.

## In the past

According to this https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/ until ubuntu 19.10 it seemed to exist `docker-ce-cli`.

But in a Focal Fossa 20.04 this happens:

```
# apt-get update
[omitted]
# apt-get install docker-ce-cli
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-cli
```

## Question

What package should I install in ubuntu 20.04 to have *only* the docker cli?

```
# apt install -y xxxxxxxxx?
```

Comment: I believe the `docker-ce-cli` package is in a custom `apt` repository provided by docker.com, rather than a default repository. See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/

Answer (score 3):

As specified in [the official source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository) :

```sh
sudo apt-get update && \
     sudo apt-get install \
        ca-certificates \
        curl \
        gnupg \
        lsb-release
    
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
    
echo \
      "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
      $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

To add repositories and package lists.

Then you can run :

```sh
sudo apt install docker-ce-cli
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

`sudo apt-get install docker-ce-cli` This might do what you need

Comment: This will work only after adding the official repo from docker.com to your `sources.list` - maybe you should include this step.

Comment: @ArturMeinild and how can you add that repo?

Comment: It's in the documentation linked in the original question. 